# Linux VMSS OS Disk Autogrow Option

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

Is there any way in which I can chose an autogrow option on the OS disk for an Azure Linux VM at the time of VMSS creation? The disk size for an Azure marketplace image is 127 GB and I want to be able to expand it without needing to restart the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature as the auto grow option on the OS disk at the time of VMSS creation.

If you would like to expand your OS disk size, you can specify the size of the operating system disk in **gigabytes** with `diskSizeGB` when you deploy VMSS with the ARM template. This value cannot be larger than 1023 GB. Reference from [VirtualMachineScaleSetOSDisk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachinescalesets#virtualmachinescalesetosdisk-object) object.

For example, specify the OS disk size is 200GiB

```
       "virtualMachineProfile": {
            "storageProfile": {
                "osDisk": {
                    "caching": "ReadWrite",
                    "createOption": "FromImage",
                    "diskSizeGB": "200"
                },
                "dataDisks": [
                    {
                    "diskSizeGB": 128,
                    "lun": 0,
                    "createOption": "Empty"
                    }
                ],
                "imageReference": "[variables('imageReference')]"
            },
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Let's say the Image size is 30 GB but when I set 100GB as the disk size in the ARM template, it would automatically increase OS disk size to 100 GB?

Comment: After my validation, When you set the OS disk size to 200 GB, you also need to [expand the volume within the OS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/expand-os-disk#expand-the-volume-within-the-os) but this does not trigger vmss instance restart.